# Setting suggested width and height to a custom view in android

Tags: android, view

I'm learning how to create custom views in android. Currently I don't understand how to set minimum width and height of it. Why do I think that it is not set? Because I print value of `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()` which returns a 0 to me.

In the view there are some figures drown on the canvas meaning there are no views under it in the hierarchy unless views are added automatically(are they btw?).

I tried googling possible ways of setting minimum width or height to a custom view but didn't find anything.

So, how do I set minimum width and height to a custom view in `onMeasure()` method? If there are some question like why would you need to override the method then the answer is that I want to learn how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring a custom view is actually easier than it looks. You should take a look at [MeasureSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec).

You generally need to handle cases where your view can be given a specific size, `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

When `onMeasure` is called, it's given `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` parameters, which you can use in combination with `MeasureSpec` to get

1. `width` and `height` mode
2. `width` and `height` size

Mode can be one of three pre-defined values in `MeasureSpec`:

> UNSPECIFIED
>
> The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child. It can be whatever size it wants.
>
> EXACTLY
>
> The parent has determined an exact size for the child. The child is going to be given those bounds regardless of how big it wants to be.
>
> AT_MOST
>
> The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.

What you need to do is to cover these cases, which ~mostly~ looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            width = //Calculation
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            width = //Calculation
        } else {
            // UNSPECIFIED
            width = //Calculation
        }

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            height = //Calculation
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            height = //Calculation
        } else {
            // UNSPECIFIED
            height = //Calculation
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

There is also case where you should measure child views if your custom view is a `ViewGroup` and can contain 1 or many child views. This is a piece of code I wrote couple years ago for measuring a custom `ViewGroup` which can have 1 child ( `mChild` ) at most and needs to calculate its height / width properties by also thinking it'll draw a stroke ( `mStrokeWidth` ) around the child.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        measureChild(mChild, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childWidth = mChild.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = mChild.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            width = Math.min(width, (int) (childWidth + (mStrokeWidth * 2)));
        }

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            height = Math.min(height, (int) (childHeight + (mStrokeWidth * 2)));
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

Comment: what is `measureChild(mChild, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);`

Comment: It's a method in `ViewGroup` itself: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#measureChild(android.view.View,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is very easy, hope it will helps

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (widthSize < MIN_WIDTH) {
      widthSize = MIN_WIDTH;
    }  

    if (heightSize < MIN_HEIGHT) {
      heightSize = MIN_HEIGHT;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSize , heightSize );
}
```

Comment: it is kind of simplified version of resolveSize(), right? And where do you get MIN_WIDTH from?  Or it must be a constant defined by my preferences of size of the view?

Comment: you can define `MIN_WIDTH` or  `MIN_HEIGHT` as constant or you can pass it from somewhere, and `withSize` and `heightSize` is the size of view in pixel